# How to change a currency symbol in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, currency

For a Magento with a Swiss franc as currency, the symbole for the german store is (FR.) i want it to be (CHF) instead.

In Magento this is declared in  lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml

But i don't want to change this file, it seems like it's a nasty way (changin the Magento  Core), is there any other solution which allows me to change this symbole ?

Answer (score 14):

You can change the currency symbols from `System->Manage Currency->Symbols`.

Comment: Its already done, the problem is : in the default store the symbole is CHF (what i want) but in german store it is not good it displays (Fr.)

Answer (score 2):

There is a helpful module "ET Currency Manager" which allows you to change the display of the currencies' symbols and also its position (right, left, ...)

Advantages : You can control the display of the price and currency symbol, the precision (number of decimal, etc ...)

Disadvantages : lot of rewrites in module (5 rewrites)

link : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

Answer (score 1):

check this link .May be it will help you

http://magentocoders.blogspot.in/2011/10/insert-rupee-symbol-instead-of-rs-in.html

Comment: Please do not write single link answers. Explain in a few words what is found at the end of that URL.

Comment: As the whole explanation is in link so it doesn't need to write same thing here that's why I didn't write anything here. From next time i will take care of it.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do it this time also. Just hit the edit button and do your magic.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in Magento 1.14.2, there is no option in Admin backend to change currency symbol per store. However, you can use installer to do this:

```
$installer = $this; 
$installer->startSetup();
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load('mystore_com');

$symbol = 'DOLLARS ';//Replace $ with DOLLARS
$currencies = unserialize(Mage::getStoreConfig('currency/options/customsymbol', $store->getId())); 

$currencies['USD'] = $symbol; 

Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('currency/options/customsymbol',
serialize($currencies), 'stores', $store->getId() );

$installer->endSetup();
```

Alternately, you can update/add table row (which contains currency/options/customsymbol) in table core_config_data.